# Symmetric matrix with zero patern

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm wondering if I can find some general formula for the inverse of such symmetric matrix :

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & -k & 0 &-k\\ -k & 1 & -k & 0\\0 & -k & 1 & -k\\-k & 0 & -k & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

which would still be valid for NxN generalization. The first line would be $$\begin{bmatrix}1 & -k & 0 & \dots & 0 & -k\end{bmatrix}$$

Or some base transformation that'd simplify the thing.

Comment: Maybe you can look into normal and circulant matrices and see if anything materializes. If you look at the structure of the inverse, there are definitely 'fixed patters', see http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+%7B%7B1%2C-k%2C0%2C-k%7D%2C%7B-k%2C1%2C-k%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C-k%2C1%2C-k%7D%2C%7B-k%2C0%2C-k%2C1%7D%7D. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inverse is simple:

$$\frac{1}{1-4k^2} \begin{bmatrix}
 1-2 k^2 & k & 2 k^2 & k \\
 k & 1-2 k^2 & k & 2 k^2 \\
 2 k^2 & k & 1-2 k^2 & k \\
 k & 2 k^2 & k & 1-2 k^2
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Your generalization, however, should be precisely defined. It is not obvious from the above what would an $n \times n$ matrix look like.

**Edit:** Your general form is a circulant matrix. For the inverse, you might want to look at the paper by Lin Fuyong, "[The inverse of circulant matrix](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0096300311004206)", or Durmuş Bozkurt's "[On the Determinants and Inverses of Circulant Matrices with a General Number Sequence](http://arxiv.org/abs/1202.1068)".

Comment: Of course for N=4 it's easy. The generalization is the key point : it's filled with zeros except for the last term : the first line would be $\begin{bmatrix}1 & -k & 0 & \dots & 0 & -k\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: I've added links to two papers you might find interesting, especially if you're writing a program to compute these.

Comment: Well. It seems I'm in a quite simple type of circulant matrix and it may be able to simplify the notation.

Comment: So far I get with Fuyong's method : $$g(z)=g(z')=1-k(z+z^{-1})$$ forall N. This polynomial has 2 zeros : $$z_1=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4k^2}}{2k}$$ and $$z_2=\frac{\sqrt{1-4k^2-1}}{2k}$$ with only $z_1$ is in the unit circle. So far so good. Now I don't understand what's $$g_1(z_1)$$ and would like some help on it.

Comment: ahem the second zero is $z_2=\frac{\sqrt{1-4k^2}+1}{2k}$

Comment: I've just read it and, frankly, I'm not sure. The paper is weird, to say the least. There are at least few errors (both in grammar and in some formulas), and I cannot understand the difference between Examples 2 and 4, which seem closest to what you need. Try to mimic just the idea from the paper, which - as far as I can see - is based on simply solving $Ax = e_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 \end{bmatrix}^T$. I'm sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: Well I plan to use the symbolic matlab toolbox for the process, so the inverse computation should be OK.

Comment: Is the other publication easier to handle or not?

Comment: The other one seems a bit more specific with the choice of the elements in $A$, which I didn't notice the first time searching for these. :-( Fuyong is probably O.K., if you can understand what exactly is he doing. I'm really surprised that such a paper passed a peer review in Appl. Math. Comput. Maybe you can e-mail him for some clarification?